# SQL - How can I concatenate a string based on an ANY result?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, any

I'm trying to write a query which aggregates many rows and returns a single string value to indicate whether or not each column contains a value.  It needs to examine each column and if the column contains a 'true' value, then concatenate the string result to indicate so.

Given (on SQL Server 2008):

```
      Col1 | Col2
Row1: 0      0
Row2: 0      1
```

I need a result stating "Col1 has no true, Col2 has true" (the comma doesn't matter).

My assumption is that I need to combine a `CASE` or `IF` statement with an `ANY` operator, but so far the syntax escapes me.

Comment: what are the datatypes of the columns?  can we assume that they are all boolean (1 or 0) as in the example?

Comment: @DmitryBeransky -- yes, the columns being evaluated are all boolean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query will produce these results: `Col1 has no true, Col2 has true` for your data:

```
SELECT CASE
          WHEN Col1Total = 0 THEN 'Col1 has no true'
          ELSE 'Col1 has true'
       END + ', ' +
   CASE
      WHEN Col2Total = 0 THEN 'Col2 has no true'
      ELSE 'col2 has true'
   END AS yourResult
FROM 
(
   SELECT SUM(Col1) AS Col1Total, SUM(Col2) AS Col2Total
   FROM yourTable
) AS t
```

Comment: Thanks, Adam! It's working in my test query, now to expand it to the real thing :)